# Gravity Forms: User-created field not posting data

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Gravity Forms in Wordpress to create a submission form for a client. Gravity Forms has most of the requirements I need for this task, but I'm having to build some custom fields into the plugin itself (which is supposed to be extensible).

As such, I am creating a field type that uploads a video file to Youtube upon post submission. I plan to use a file upload input type, and upon submission grab the file data (or url/pathname) and upload it to Youtube. This is part of a client project that I have to build in three weeks.

I've created a custom field by using the following hooks: (sorry for the terrible formatting; links and code don't mix well)

`add_action("`[`gform_field_input`](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_field_input)`", array('GFYoutubeUpload', 'add_gf_fieldtype'), 10, 5)`

`add_filter("`[`gform_editor_js_set_default_values`](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_editor_js_set_default_values)`", array('GFYoutubeUpload', 'add_gf_defaults'));`

`add_action("`[`gform_editor_js`](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_editor_js)`", array('GFYoutubeUpload', 'add_gf_formeditor'));`

`add_filter("`[`gform_field_type_title`](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_field_type_title)`", array('GFYoutubeUpload', 'add_gf_title'));`

`add_filter("`[`gform_add_field_buttons`](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_add_field_buttons)`", array('GFYoutubeUpload', 'add_gf_button'));`

(I also have a [pre_submission](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_pre_submission) handler that I've begun to write that will send the input to a different plugin.)

I've created a File input type, and I believe that I have the correct naming convention. I've posted my function below for review.) The input type is displaying correctly on the Wordpress admin page and the Gravity Forms form preview, but when I post the form, my custom field doesn't have a value associated with it. (There's nothing in $_POST corresponding to it, either.)

Looking at the code below, can anybody tell me where I've gone wrong creating this input? Is there another hook that I don't know about that I need to use to handle the data I've added to the form?

```
<?php
     /* Register the cusitom field type with Gravity Forms. */ 
     public static function add_gf_fieldtype($input, $field, $value, $lead_id, $form_id) {  
         if ($field["type"] == "youtube") {  
             $input_name = $form_id .'_'. $field['id'];  
             $css = isset($field['cssClass']) ? $field['cssClass'] : '';  

             return sprintf("<div class='ginput_container'><input name='input_%s' id='input_%s_%s' class='%s' value='' type='file' /></div>", $field["id"], $form_id, $field["id"], $field["type"]. ' ' .esc_attr($css). ' ' .$field['size']);  
         }  

         return $input;  
     }
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually simple - it wasn't Gravity Forms; it was basic PHP. I was  using the `$_POST` superglobal instead of `$_FILES`, where the data actually lived. Hopefully, this will help someone else who runs into this problem.